# Taking a low-quality picture of the screen

Tags: c#, image

I want to be able to take a low-quality image of the screen. I can take a bitmap picture, but no matter what I do I can't lower its quality.

Comment: Do you mean reducing the color depth or reducing the number of pixels?

Comment: Whatever I can to reduce the filesize.

Comment: or do you want to keep the resolution and convert it into a lossy compressed format like png or jpeg?

Comment: Again, anything that reduces the filesize. I'm trying to make a screen-sharing application as a test, so I need to stream images over a network. Therefore, they have to be very small in size.

Comment: So, you essentially want to create a video stream? Then possibly looking around for tutorials on how to create compressed video from a series of images would help, or edit you question to be more descriptive. Just creating a series of (compressed) images will not give you compression near to what is possible. Especially compared tp video compression codecs specifically made for efficient encoding of screen-recording videos.

Comment: You could also reduce the size by calculating what areas of the screen have changed since the last frame, and only tramsitting that, perhaps

Answer (score 3):

```
Image bmp1 = GetScreenImage ();

// Save the image as a GIF.
bmp1.Save("c:\\button.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

[Msdn for more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I would try converting the image to a compressed jpeg.  The nice thing about jpegs is that you can set how high the quality should be (i.e. how much you want it compressed):

Note: quality should be between 1 and 100 (100 being the largest size/highest quality and  1 being the smallest size/lowest quality.

```
public void save(string filename, Bitmap img, int quality)
{
   // quality encoding
   EncoderParameter qualParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality);

   // code for jpeg image type
   ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = FindEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");


   EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
   encoderParams.Param[0] = qualParam;

   img.Save(filename, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
}

private ImageCodecInfo FindEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
{
   // search through all codecs for all formats
   ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

   for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++)
   {
      if (codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType)
      {
         return codecs[i];
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```